# Pyqt how to get a widget's dimensions

Tags: python, widget, size, pyqt

I am currently developing an application in which i cannot use modal windows (due to some application constraints). However, in some cases i would like to simulate a popup window. To do so i dynamically create a widget that has the centralwidget as parent and i use the move() method to place it where i want.
I would like to know if there is a way to get a widget's dimensions at a given time (considering the mainWindow can be resized at any time) so that i will be able to center the placeholder popup (a simple widget) at the middle of the centralwidget.

Thank you

Comment: For those looking for actual QWidget size (inner size): If you want to know the size of the widget usable space (the inner space), you need to use `geometry`, not `frameGeometry` which adds the size of the window frame to the widget own size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`frameGeometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#frameGeometry-prop) or [`geometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) depending on [your needs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/application-windows.html#window-geometry).

Comment: This is not a correct answer if you don't give a working example. Copy-pasting docs only is not an answer. Therefore @subin george gave the correct answers.

Comment: @GLHF although you are correct with your statement... OP doesn't give code. Its all theoretical; therefore I Avaris his theorectical answer is correct as well ;-))

Answer (score 40):

> For getting Qt Widget size:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

mainWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
width = mainWindow.frameGeometry().width()
height = mainWindow.frameGeometry().height()
```

Comment: two other useful parameters are: .left() and .top()

Answer (score 17):

> For gettting screen size

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

mainWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
screenShape = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
mainWindow.resize(self.screenShape.width(), self.screenShape.height())
mainWindow.show()
```