# PyQt4 how to get button size

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, button, pyqt

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204470/pyqt-how-to-get-a-widgets-dimensions) and [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) and I have also tried:

```
self.myButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Click")
a = self.myButton.size()
print a
```

things like these, but I'm still unable to get a single button's size info. When I `print a`, it returns the size of the parent window, I think. Basically it returns a size that is clearly not the button's size because the return value is too big to be that button's size. Yes I feel like this is a very newbie question but I am just stuck with this. I'd appreciate your help with this, thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to parent the widget or put it in a layout for it to be able to calculate its size.  Without a specified parent, it is kind of lost.

Comment: You are right. After setting its parent as self, it now returns me the correct size. I would like to up-vote or set your answer as correct but it appears I can do neither since your answer is a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parent the widget or put it in a layout for it to be able to calculate its size. Without a specified parent, it is kind of lost...

...or rather it thinks it is going to be a window by itself and uses the minimum size for a window for the platform you are on.

Hope that helps.